# What does meaning-scepticism mean?

Tags: terminology, skepticism

I found the term in The Limits of Realism (Tim Button) (2013) on page 2:

> We are, then, looking for an argument that forces realists to consider
> semantic questions. A natural place to look is in the discussion of
> **meaning scepticism** that took America by storm in the 1960s onwards,
> culminating in Hilary Putnam's model-theoretic arguments against a
> certain kind of realism. This is my entry point to the realism debate.

(emphasis mine)

[Apparently, there's a book named after it as well.](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALiCzsaPhXZ1wUYvia4GDx_fRCASPL9_6w:1669461173499&q=Meaning%20Scepticism&si=AC1wQDBXv9Wd8FgWfDzdvZ5PhOlHksbX2hYqeJie3ahNAc1QV4PVE20OGwRHQTwfMNeSai2Q0RolHt1QSk4YORJZ4K97S8jVdjsWZDr6y1DrO5cAw5oll5Q%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-q73D28v7AhXFVHwKHa9zBtQQnZMFegQIIBAC&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1&ictx=1#wptab=si:AC1wQDBXv9Wd8FgWfDzdvZ5PhOlHksbX2hYqeJie3ahNAc1QV4PVE20OGwRHQTwfMNeSai2Q0RolHt1QSk4YORJZ4K97S8jVdjsWZDr6y1DrO5cAw5oll5Q%3D) I know what scepticism means, but what does meaning scepticism mean exactly?

Comment: It is not a standard term and refers to the rejection of traditional semantics (sometimes called denotationalism), according to which the primary meaning of linguistic expressions is some sort of idea or abstract object they label, what Frege called "sense" and Mill "denotation". Wittgenstein traced this view back to St. Augustin, and took it as a backdrop to present his alternative, under the motto "meaning is use". It became popular since 1960s. See [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning/#AlteClasSemaTheo) for a survey of "skeptical" theories of meaning.

Comment: Search the famous Kripkenstein meaning paradox against meaning realism/factualism which forced various kinds of realists to consider semantic questions seriously, and its effect was resurrecting some traditional metaphysics questions and further exposed possibly serious limitations of once popular and authoritative logical positivism...